# Invalid argument foreach

Tags: codeigniter

**View code**

```
<?php foreach($payment as $test){?>
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $test->customerName;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $test->dateTime;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $test->amount;?></td>
  </tr>    
 <?php }?>
```

**Controller code**

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('Income_sales_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->data['pja_test'] = $this->Income_sales_model->get_all();
    $this->load->view('income_sales_view', $data);
}
```

**AND HERE IS MY ERROR **

[I'm stuck here I don't know what to do..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyJC7.png)

Answer (score 1):

the variable you are trying to access must be a key of `$data`...
So,`print_r($pja_test);die;` in your view you will get the appropriate output
If still any issue let me know

Comment: i still have a problem with my view code undefined variable and invalidargument in my foreach @kunal

Comment: can you show the code I still don't know where to put what you said @kunal

Comment: ohh...
replace it
 $this->data['pja_test'] = $this->Income_sales_model->get_all();

with

 $data['payment'] = $this->Income_sales_model->get_all();

Comment: It's stilt the same error. undefined variable and invalidargument in my foreach @kunal.... Why is it not working :(

Comment: Please provide more details i have to see your model code...I can't get any more idea with given description....@jeremyAvila

Comment: `function get_all() {
    $this->db->select('customerName, dateTime, amount');
    $query = $this->db->get('payment');
    return $query->result_array();
  }`
here my moder @kunal

Comment: debug now using...echo $this->db->last_query();die;
in your model after query execution..
You will get the query which runs actually...
now copy it and run in your mysql...is it producing desired output or not??

Answer (score 0):

**Controller code**

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('Income_sales_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $data['payment'] = $this->Income_sales_model->get_all();  // $query->result();
    $this->load->view('income_sales_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: i still get the same error
`Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: payment
Filename: views/income_sales_view.php
Line Number: 16`
`Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: views/income_sales_view.php
Line Number: 16`

Comment: the same as the picture in my question @swap

Comment: print_r($data['payment']); into controller and checked correct payment data